# React: Clear fields on submit

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
{inputFields.map((inputField, index) => (
<Fragment key={`${inputField}~${index}`}>
<Select isClearable classNamePrefix="select" ref={myRef} menuPortalTarget={document.body} styles={style} placeholder="Select Foods" name="Foods" value={inputField.foods} options={options} onChange={event => handleInputChange2(index, event)} className="select selectNarrow" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<TextField InputLabelProps={{shrink: true,}} id="standard-basic" label="Quantity" value={inputField.Quantity} name="Quantity" onChange={event => handleInputChange(index, event)} type="number" variant="outlined" InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0, max: 100 } }} />
</Fragment>
))}
```

What I am trying to do is after submit, clear both of these fields.

```
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    { Food: '', Quantity: '' }
]);

const handleInputChange2 = (index, event) => {
    if (!event) {
      event = {
        label: '',
        value: '',
      };
    }
    const values = [...inputFields];
    values[index] = event;
    setInputFields(values);
};
```

If I try adding setInputFields(null) I get the error on submit:
**inputFields.map is not a function**

Any idea on how I can clear these fields after submit?

Comment: Please, show what you have in inputFields by default

Comment: By default it is an array - [
    {
        "Food": "",
        "Quantity": ""
    }
]

Comment: How on submit function looks like?

Comment: const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("meals")
      .add({
        Name : name,
        Serves : serves,
        Method : mealmethod,
        Foods : inputFields
      })
      .then(() => setName(""), setServes(""), setCountry(null), setLang(null), setMethod(""), setFoods(null))
  };

Comment: @PaulVI just revert the state of your fields to default after submitting: `setInputFields(YOUR_INITIAL_STATE)`

Comment: If I do that setInputFields(...inputFields) on my .then it still returns the same error inputFields.map is not a function

Comment: Sorry, if I use setInputFields(inputFields) then no error - but the value in the select still remains

Answer (score 0):

```
const INITIAL_STATE = [ { "Food": "", "Quantity": "" } ];
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);
```

After submitting:

```
setInputFields(INITIAL_STATE);
```

Comment: It still remains - does the fact that it is in an array matter? Do I need to reference index at all?

Comment: @PaulVI The array shouldn't be a problem. Better to reference the field `name`, like: `[e.target.name]: e.target.value`

Comment: Sorry, it does in fact clear it, but the option label still remains - how do I clear it so the placeholder comes back?

Comment: as above the select option is still visible?

Comment: @PaulVI can u reproduce you problem with codesandbox, etc?

Comment: I think I have to somehow clear the label on that select…

Answer (score 0):

In your function that handles submission, do this:

```
const handleSubmission = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Say you're submitting to a server using axios,
    try{
       await axios.post(URL, {...data to submit}, {
            headers: {}
        });
        // On successful submission, clear all fields
        setInputFields({
            Food: '',
            Quantity: '',
        });
    catch(error){
        ...handle errors
    }
```

I'd suggest you write your onSubmit like so:

```
onSubmit={e => handleSubmission(e)}
```

Comment: I don’t use axios and am already doing this

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're using axios. You're probably submitting to a backend; so use fetch or any other module that is of convenience to you...